# Connection not available while invoking method createOrWaitForConnection for resource?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

Application on spring4+jaxb+jpa  deployd on websphere 8.5.5.13 and oracle11g

Sometimes, I see error messages link with max connection pool size:

> Connection not available while invoking method
>   createOrWaitForConnection for resource

So, what is the correct fix for it
1. just increase pool connections size till 50
2. Code refactoring

Do you see some unlclosed connections in my code, do I have rude error when use JPA?

my service is:

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;
    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserService.class);


    public List<User> find(String name, String surname, List<String> types) throws Exception {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "UserService.find()[find by params..]");
        Assert.isTrue(name != null || surname != null,
                "Один из параметров name или surname обязательны для получения риск-метрики");

        List<UserRecord> UserRecords = new ArrayList<>();
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(types)) {
            UserRecords.addAll(find(name, surname));
        } else {
            types.stream().forEach(type -> UserRecords.addAll(find(name, surname, type)));
        }

        return extractUsers(UserRecords);
    }

    public List<User> find(String id) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "UserService.find()[find by id]");
        UserRecord UserRecord = repository.findOne(id);
        if (UserRecord == null) return Collections.emptyList();

        User User = (User) deserialize(UserRecord.getUser());
        User.setVersion(UserRecord.getVersion());
        User.setObjectId(UserRecord.getPrKey());

        return Collections.singletonList(User);
    }

    private List<User> extractUsers(List<UserRecord> UserRecords) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "UserService.extractUsers()");
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(UserRecords) || UserRecords.stream().allMatch(x -> x == null)) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }

        return UserRecords.stream().map(UserRecord -> {
            User User = (User) deserialize(UserRecord.getUser());
            User.setVersion(UserRecord.getVersion());
            User.setObjectId(UserRecord.getPrKey());
            return User;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private List<UserRecord> find(String name, String surname, String UserType) {
        List<UserRecord> UserRecords;
        if (name != null && surname != null) {
            UserRecords = repository.findUserRecordsByNameAndSurnameAndUserType(name, surname, UserType);
        } else {
            if (name == null) {
                UserRecords = repository.findUserRecordsBySurnameAndUserType(surname, UserType);
            } else {
                UserRecords = repository.findUserRecordsByNameAndUserType(name, UserType);
            }
        }

        return UserRecords.stream().allMatch(x -> x == null) ? new ArrayList<>() : UserRecords;
    }

    private List<UserRecord> find(String name, String surname) {
        List<UserRecord> UserRecords;
        if (name != null && surname != null) {
            UserRecords = repository.findUserRecordsByNameAndSurname(name, surname);
        } else {
            if (name == null) {
                UserRecords = repository.findUserRecordsBySurname(surname);
            } else {
                UserRecords = repository.findUserRecordsByName(name);
            }
        }

        return UserRecords;
    }
}

class UserComparator implements Comparator<User> {
    @Override
    public int compare(User o1, User o2) {
        return Integer.compare(o1.getVersion(), o2.getVersion());
    }
}
```

My Jpa entity is:

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "userRecord", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"name", "surname", "userType", "idCalc"})})
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class userRecord {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "PR_KEY")
    private String prKey;

    //Business Key
    @Column(name = "name", length = 100, unique = false)
    private String name;

    //Business Key
    @Column(name = "surname", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String surname;

    //Business Key
    @Column(name = "userType", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String userType;

    //Business Key
    @Column(name = "idCalc", length = 64, nullable = false)
    private String idCalc;

    @Version
    private int version;

    @Column(name = "user", length = 100000)
    @Lob
    private byte[] user;

    public userRecord(String name, String surname, String userType, byte[] user) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.userType = userType;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public userRecord(String name, String surname, String userType,
                            String idCalc, byte[] user) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.userType = userType;
        this.user = user;
        this.idCalc = idCalc;
    }
}
```

My repository is:

```
@Repository
public interface RickMetricRepository extends CrudRepository<userRecord, String> {
    List<userRecord> finduserRecordsBynameAndsurnameAnduserType(
            String name, String surname, String userType);

    userRecord finduserRecordBynameAndsurnameAnduserTypeAndIdCalc(
            String name, String surname, String userType, String idCalc);

    List<userRecord> finduserRecordsBynameAndsurname(String name, String surname);

    List<userRecord> finduserRecordsBysurname(String surname);

    List<userRecord> finduserRecordsBysurnameAnduserType(String surname, String userType);

    List<userRecord> finduserRecordsBynameAnduserType(String name, String userType);

    List<userRecord> finduserRecordsByname(String name);

    userRecord finduserRecordByPrKey(String id);
}
```

**Do I need some CLOSE CONNECTION operations?**

Answer (score 1):

In normal scenario, there is no connection is in-use for much long time frame unless there is a connection leak. So it is very clear that application is not closing the connection. Application need to close the connection once its done its job.

This issue mainly occur during the new application deployment when application is not closing the connection or when there is a connection leak. Every connection should be in this pattern: Get/Use/Close

When you see this type of error in traces for new applications the very first place to check is connection code pattern in the new application. It should follow get-use-close connection. Each connection should be closed properly, then only connection is returned back to the pool and it is ready to use for the next `getConnection` call. If application is not closing the connection and running out of connections then new `getConnection` requests are not able to get the connection with in its `ConnectionWaitTimeout` interval.

You can get more information [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1205_ramachandra/1205_ramachandra.html).

Comment: And How to do this? Do I need to mark my service method like @Transactional?